# A very specific bar chord problem

Tags: guitar, chords, acoustic-guitar, fingering

There are loads of posts about bar chords but this one is a specific problem.

So I can bar all strings on each fret without any trouble, not even much pressure, even without using my thumb on the back. I do this by positioning my barring finger as close to the fret below as possible then rotate my barring finger toward the neck so the edge of my finger is the contact point.

The piece I am learning has a B7sus2 with F# BASS chord which is as follows:

I bar the 2nd fret then have one finger on Fret 5 on the second string and one finger on Fret 4 on the fourth string

I bar the second fret with my forefinger no problem but now when I try and add my other fingers so one finger is on Fret 5 on the second string and one finger is on Fret 4 on the fourth string and then I lose my bar because as I move my little/pinkie finger to reach the fifth fret I can no longer roll my barring finger towards the neck. Other bar chords like E shape and A shape I have no problem with.

Any suggestions?

Comment: B7sus2? Or B7sus4?

Comment: You're playing `B7sus4/F#` not a `sus2`, but regardless can you play this chord shape clearly if you set the bar at fret 5? The chord will be `D7sus4/A`. I'm trying to get at whether the issue is the long reach of the pinky and your wrist position.

Comment: Surely B7sus2 disregards the 3rd, but a fully formed B9 includes the 3rd?

Comment: If you can, please post a pic of you playing the chord.  How do we know you  trouble isn't the size of your hand?  This would help.  I would be inclined to post some of my hand position if I can see an obvious issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Move your thumb more towards the 4th fret**. Maybe a slight extra arch in your pinky at 5th fret is making your index curve, Moving your thumb must do.

**Tilt your index finger slightly so that** it 's slightly turning towards the bridge side, get the **more muscular part of your index hold the bar**. I used to miss this when I was new to barr chords and half the time my notes were muted.

Answer (score -1):

To play a simpler chord try 2,2,1,2,0,0.That gives you F♯ underneath, B, D♯, A, and the sus (4) E on top. Voicing isn't quite so good, but it's a lot easier!

Comment: I tried muting string 4 - `22x200` - because the original chord had no third. I think this is good non-barre alternative. The main difference seems to be the missing `F#` on top.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - my comment appears to have disappeared. Of course, there's no need for D#. That gets replaced by the sus 4 note E (if indeed it is sus4). Another way is 222202, which puts the sus in the middle, keeps the F# at the bottom, and puts F# also at the top.